# Using port 587 to send email

Tags: smtp, port

I want to use port 587 to send email using an SMTP server via SSL or without SSL even. Is there any free email clients that can help me out here? My port 465 and 25 are blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many email clients that may meet your demand such as Foxmail and Thunderbird.
You can add a new account with manually without automatical config.

But you should make sure that the SMTP sever is using port 587 but not port 465 or 25. This should be configured in the server.